# deploying destructive changes

Tags: apex, deployment, destructivechanges.xml

i'm deploying a destructive change (includes apex classes) into a production environment and it kick starts running all tests. This didn't happen when doing it on the sandbox environments. Any way I can bypass this or even running specified tests?

Comment: You need to verify if you were using the same ant task in your sandbox and production environment. You cannot bypass tests in production, but if you have right ant task, you can always specify specific tests.

Comment: so would I specify tests for the classes being deleted?

Comment: You cannot run "Specified" tests while deploying anything to prod....

Comment: @SebastianKessel - You [can specify](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm) in production as well.

Comment: I'll be damned. Good Catch.

Comment: Yes, you can specify in pro - I just ran regular deployment using specifiedtests, just wondering if I could do the same with the destructive changes. and if so, would I specify the test covering the classes i would be deleting?

Comment: @JPG - No. Because that will fail anyways as your classes won't exist. You should in fact include such test classes in destructive changes as well. So that those get deleted with the classes as well.

Comment: @JayantDas yes I agree, in the xml i'm including the deletion of the test classes. So if I run specifiedtests on destructive how should I structure it?

Comment: Any of your specified tests doesn't reside in either package.xml or desctructivechanges.xml. You mention what you need to run in your ant task, so just don't include those there and that should work.

Comment: @JayantDas thanks, will try removing the test classes from the  desctructivechanges.xml and running specifiedtests.

Comment: @JayantDas I tried running the desctructivechanges.xml again with specifiedtests and they deployed however i got "no tests were run" which I find bizarre behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't. Every time you push any type of code to a production environment Salesforce is going to force the deployment to `RunAllTests`. In sandboxes this is a value you can control, but not on production. This is to ensure that all code compiles and your tests still work after destructing.

As an example, imagine accidentally removing a trigger that impacts your application's behavior. Tests running would ensure that you catch that problem before your production org starts failing.

[This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm) document contains more details. Please note that a "destructive deployment" is still a deployment and thus has to comply with the same rules.

Here is the relevant excerpt:

> When deploying to production, all tests, except those that originate from managed packages, are executed if your deployment package contains Apex classes or triggers. If your package doesn’t contain Apex components, no tests are run by default.

EDIT:

Thanks to @JayantDas, you can run Specified Tests on a prod deploy. See [here](http://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm). The big caveat is that every single class you test has to meet the 75% threshold. With "All Tests" it's a combined 75% (except for triggers).

Comment: Would I be able to run specified tests on a destructive changes xml?

Comment: Nope. It's all unmanaged tests. You have no control over this.

Comment: Not sure which tool you are using, but generally you should be able to push destructive changes + run specific test class. In such case, you can simply mentioned 1 test class which you know it is valid. + With that being said, you should be careful about this process, as deleting some code might reduce your coverage and therefore might cause for future errors in the next deployments.